# DC circuit and capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

What method should I use to calculate the voltage across C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>2</sub> in the following circuit in DC conditions?

[image]

I've already tried using KCL, but I'm confused with what point on the circuit to use. Is it using a transform? Should I add a ground to the circuit?

Comment: Hint: what is the DC resistance of a capacitor?

Comment: infinite, but i still don't understand :(

Comment: @AgathaH Would you please share the `tried using KCL` part? I get it that you are confused and you may feel that you don't want to share the KCL you developed. But it's important to see what/how you tried to do things. Also, when you say `infinite, but i still don't understand` do you mean that you don't understand why, at DC, capacitors can be treated as infinite impedance? Or something else?

Comment: @periblepsis i don't understand how to apply that infinite on calculation

Comment: Is the question about steady state DC? If yes, capacitors are open circuits. Replace them with open circuits.

Comment: @AgathaH If this is a question about the state of affairs at \$t\to\infty\$ then you can just cut the capacitors out of the circuit and leave holes where they used to be, then solve without them. If this is a question where initial conditions are specified for the two capacitors and you need to work out the changes over time from there, then that's another issue. Which is it?

Comment: @periblepsis the question asks to calculate voltage on c1 and c2

Comment: @AgathaHadasa Calculating the final voltage across them does not prevent you from replacing them with an open circuit/infinite resistor.

Comment: @AgathaH Well, I'd also use the context of the classwork to tell the final meaning, then. And since I'm not there and you haven't disclosed where the class is at right now, I can only guess. (Crystal ball is broken, sadly.) So, let's just say it's at \$t\to\infty\$ then. Remove them from the circuit, compute the node voltages, then place the capacitors back in place and just assign the numbers to their two ends. The differences will be the values to use. I recommend assigning 0 V to the bottom node in your diagram.

Comment: @AgathaH Ah. I see there's no values for the capacitors. So yes I do think this is about \$t\to\infty\$. So the capacitors can be removed for analysis and then placed back for getting the values you want.

Comment: Try replacing that current source and 3K with a Thevenen equivalent voltage source.  All will become clear then.  Clarifying an earlier hint:  the capacitors don't affect DC current flow, so in the steady state, they can be ignored (open) for voltage analysis.

Comment: May l know Why this question is down voated

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is referring to DC conditions, you are interested only in the state of the system after all voltages and currents have *stopped* changing. This state is called "quiescent", or the "DC operating point".

In this quiescent state, all capacitors will have charged to their final long-term voltages, and currents through them will have fallen to zero. Similarly, voltages across all inductors will have become zero.

A capacitor that isn't passing any current is, for all intents and purposes, an open circuit. An inductor with zero volts across it is, effectively, a short-circuit. This means that you can remove all capacitors, and replace all inductors with short circuits, without altering the quiescent state at all:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF7QqI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Optionally you can simplify this by replacing \$I_1\$ and \$R_1\$ with their Thevenin equivalent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8z2ap.png)</sup>

It's now easy to calculate the potential differences between any pair of nodes. Whatever you calculate from this schematic, will be the *long-term* conditions present in the original schematic, after all capacitor currents have fallen to zero.

For example, the potential difference \$V_{AB}=V_A-V_B\$ will be \$V_1\$, the voltage across \$C_1\$, after a long time, when everything has settled.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are resistor values given, but no capacitor values provided, I can surmise that the problem is about the values on the capacitors `after a very long time.`

The schematic is also missing a reference node value. Let me make clear what I mean:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ3ZXw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just for a moment open your mind and wonder about the following: Assume that \$V_a=100\:\text{V}\$, \$V_x=200\:\text{V}\$, \$V_y=150\:\text{V}\$, and \$V_z=140\:\text{V}\$. (I just made up those values. Don't treat them as true.) Would that actually be any different than if \$V_a=0\:\text{V}\$, \$V_x=100\:\text{V}\$, \$V_y=50\:\text{V}\$, and \$V_z=40\:\text{V}\$? It would ***not*** make any difference. We can add or subtract any voltage value from the nodes, so long as we do the same to ***all*** of them. equally. Circuits work on voltage differences.

Now, we could just keep things abstract and leave, for example, \$V_a\$, as the reference voltage but not assign it any specific value. In that case, we'd have to add the symbol \$V_a\$ to everything else. But that's just inconvenient to do. So most everyone will instead just assign \$V_a=0\:\text{V}\$ and work out the other three node values, from that assumption.

You are allowed to pick any of the nodes and make it the reference node and assign it \$0\:\text{V}\$. But it's a good idea to pick one. I'd pick \$V_a\$ here. I hope you agree. If so, this is what remains:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsA4Pw.png)</sup>

*Note that I've disconnected (temporarily) the capacitors.*

You should be able to work out the values for \$V_x\$, \$V_y\$, and \$V_z\$ using KCL (if you want) or by using Norton-to-Thevenin conversion of \$I_1\$ and \$R_1\$ as another starting idea or by seeing that \$R_2+R_3\$ is in parallel to \$R_1\$, first, and converting that to a new combined resistance before applying a Norton-to-Thevenin conversion. Etc. Lots of ways to go.

Once you solve specific values for \$V_x\$, \$V_y\$, and \$V_z\$ you can then simply reconnect \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ and let them take on the indicated voltages for the nodes. So, \$V_{C_1}=V_x\$ and \$V_{C_2}=V_z\$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

The analysis of the circuit and the calculation of the two required voltages is very simple if the circuit is considered in stationary conditions, i.e. when the transient is considered finite. Both cases are examined in the photo:
[image]